# A word or phrasal verb in place of "Compromise"

Tags: word-choice

Can we use *get in* instead of *compromise* in the sentence below where I try to say "I don't want to argue with my wife and I make sacrifices from myself and endure the problems"?  I am just not sure this is explaining exactly what I want to say, though.

> I get all problems and conflicts in to avoid arguments with my wife.
>
> I swallowed all the problems to avoid arguments with my wife.

If this is not correct, can somebody tell me which phrasal verb and other word I can use in place of this? I am trying to improve my vocabulary and use other words in public as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrasal verb *get in* is not the same as *compromise*. It [means](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+in):

> To become or cause to become involved: *She got in with the wrong crowd. Repeated loans from the finance company got me deeper in debt.*

So, if you say that you *get in* fights, you are actually fighting with your wife. This would not alleviate arguments. (On a side note: with a phrasal verb, don't separate the verb from the attached preposition—you would write "I get in all problems..." instead of "I get all problems in".)

You could say that you "work through" problems with your wife—that is, you two come across an issue and then solve it.

Comment: So you say "Get In" doesn't mean the same thing as "I swallow all the problems to avoid the arguments with my wife"?

Comment: @Braveyard: Far from it. You can "get in" trouble by fighting with your wife, but the phrase is essentially the opposite of "swallowing all problems to avoid the arguments".

Comment: I think what OP is trying to convey here is something along the lines of *"I internalise [conflicts] to avoid overt arguments [with my wife]"*. I can't think of any common colloquial way of saying exactly that. The best I can come up with is **I'm "anything for a quiet life" with my wife**, which would be generally understood to have that meaning.

Comment: excellent comment @FumbleFingers, +1